# Sum values from two columns in the group if not duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, duplicates

I have pandas dataframes that look similar to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"week": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   "area1_code1": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "C"],
                   "area1_code2": ["A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "C1"],
                   "area1_member": [10, 10, 8, 8, 2],
                   "area2_code1": ["B", "B", "B", "B", "D"],
                   "area2_code2": ["B1", "B2", "B1", "B2", "D1"],
                   "area2_member": [3, 3, 3, 3, 6]})
```

| week | area1_code1 | area1_code2 | area1_member | area2_code1 | area2_code2 | area2_member |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A1 | 10 | B | B1 | 3 |
| 1 | A | A1 | 10 | B | B2 | 3 |
| 1 | A | A2 | 8 | B | B1 | 3 |
| 1 | A | A2 | 8 | B | B2 | 3 |
| 1 | C | C1 | 2 | D | D1 | 6 |

I want to group the data by area1_code1 and area2_code1 or by week then find the sum of area1_member and area2_member of all unique area1_code2 and area2_code2 in the group.

Desired output by area1_code1 and area2_code1:

| week | area1_code1 | area2_code1 | members |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | 24 |
| 1 | C | D | 8 |

Desired output by week:

| week | members |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 |

I have tried the following which did not give me the desired result by area1_code1 and area2_code1 though it produced the correct result by week.

```
area1 = df[["week", "area1_code1", "area1_code2", "area1_member"]].drop_duplicates(["week", "area1_code2"])
area1.rename(columns={"area1_code1": "area_code1",
                      "area1_code2": "area_code2",
                      "area1_member": "area_member"}, inplace=True)
area2 = df[["week", "area2_code1", "area2_code2", "area2_member"]].drop_duplicates(["week", "area2_code2"])
area2.rename(columns={"area2_code1": "area_code1",
                      "area2_code2": "area_code2",
                      "area2_member": "area_member"}, inplace=True)
result = pd.concat([area1, area2]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

| week | area_code1 | area_code2 | area_member |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A1 | 10 |
| 1 | A | A2 | 8 |
| 1 | C | C1 | 2 |
| 1 | B | B1 | 3 |
| 1 | B | B2 | 3 |
| 1 | D | D1 | 6 |

```
result_week = result.groupby("week")["area_member"].sum().reset_index()
```

| week | area_member |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 |

I have to do this for hundreds of dataframes with more than a million rows. What would be the most efficient solution to this problem?

Thanks!

---

### **Edited**

The members of B1 and B2 could be different e.g. B1 could be 3 and B2 could be 4. @Laurent B.'s answer would give the correct results if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proposed code:**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"week": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   "area1_code1": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "C"],
                   "area1_code2": ["A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "C1"],
                   "area1_member": [10, 10, 8, 8, 2],
                   "area2_code1": ["B", "B", "B", "B", "D"],
                   "area2_code2": ["B1", "B2", "B1", "B2", "D1"],
                   "area2_member": [3, 3, 3, 3, 6]})

def func(g):
    # Selective duplicate dropping
    g1 = g.drop_duplicates(["area1_code2"], ignore_index=True)
    g2 = g.drop_duplicates(["area2_code2"], ignore_index=True)
    # Perform and add calculations to Members list
    return g1["area1_member"].sum()+g2["area2_member"].sum()

g_cols = ["week", "area1_code1", "area2_code1"]
# Add  'Members' dataframe
r1 = df[g_cols].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
# Pass each filtered group by 'g_cols' to function 'func'
r2 = df.groupby(g_cols).apply(lambda g : func(g)).to_frame(name="Members").reset_index(drop=True)
r = r1.merge(r2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(r)
```

**Result:**

```
   week area1_code1 area2_code1  Members
0     1           A           B       24
1     1           C           D        8
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you wanna do this:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['week', 'area1_code1', 'area2_code1', 'area1_code2'])
df['all_members'] = df['area1_member'] + df['area2_member']
result = df.groupby(['week', 'area1_code1', 'area2_code1'])['all_members'].sum().reset_index()
result_week = df.groupby(['week'])['all_members'].sum().reset_index()
```

output :

```
   week area1_code1 area2_code1  all_members
0     1           A           B           24
1     1           C           D            8

   week  all_members
0     1           32
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
member_cols = ["area1_member", "area2_member"]
g_cols = ["week", "area1_code1", "area2_code1"]

#Compute sum across axis 1 for member_cols and assign a column and drop duplicates
t = df.assign(area_member=df[member_cols].sum(1)).drop_duplicates(
    [*g_cols, "area_member"], ignore_index=True
)

#Then groupby the groupby cols and just sum the "area_member"
out_1 = t.groupby(g_cols, as_index=False)["area_member"].sum()

#Then groupby week and again sum
out_2 = out_1.groupby("week", as_index=False)["area_member"].sum()

print(out_1)
   week area1_code1 area2_code1  area_member
0     1           A           B           24
1     1           C           D            8

print(out_2)
    week  area_member
0     1           32
```